# Slowness on form and general lack of knowledge

Tags: c#, windows, forms, datagridview, combobox

The speed difference between 2 combo boxes is noticeable. Plus speaking of noticeable, I've got a noticeable lack of knowledge in windows form programming. I've got a combo box on a windows form. I've got a combo box in a `datagridview`. The combo box in the `datagridview` hesitates and you have to click again to get the drop down to show up the choices.

[Screenshot of Form GUI](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RjH3T.png)

**Program.cs**

```cs
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace WindowsFormsApplication1
{
    static class Program
    {
        /// <summary>
        /// The main entry point for the application.
        /// </summary>
        [STAThread]
        static void Main()
        {
            Application.EnableVisualStyles();
            Application.SetCompatibleTextRenderingDefault(false);
            Application.Run(new Form1());
        }
    }
}
```

**Form1.Designer.cs**

```cs
namespace WindowsFormsApplication1
{
    partial class Form1
    {
        /// <summary>
        /// Required designer variable.
        /// </summary>
        private System.ComponentModel.IContainer components = null;

        /// <summary>
        /// Clean up any resources being used.
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="disposing">true if managed resources should be disposed; otherwise, false.</param>
        protected override void Dispose(bool disposing)
        {
            if (disposing && (components != null))
            {
                components.Dispose();
            }
            base.Dispose(disposing);
        }

        #region Windows Form Designer generated code

        #endregion

        private System.Windows.Forms.ComboBox comboBox1;
        private System.Windows.Forms.DataGridView dataGridView1;
        private System.Windows.Forms.DataGridViewComboBoxColumn Column1;
    }
}
```

**Form1.cs**

```cs
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace WindowsFormsApplication1
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            // fill combo box
            comboBox1.Items.Add("Trump");
            comboBox1.Items.Add("DeSantis");
            comboBox1.Items.Add("Other");

            // fill biden like slow combo box in data grid view column combo box
            Column1.Items.Add("Biden");
            Column1.Items.Add("Kennedy");
            Column1.Items.Add("Wilson");
        }
    }
}
```

When I click on the different combo boxes I get different behaviour. Can someone explain this to me and/or find a fix?

Comment: What's the question exactly? We can't help you with "lack of knowledge in windows form programming" you are going to need to read up (although WinForms is mostly dead now). And the speed difference is because they are two different components: `DataGridView`is known to be very slow.

Comment: @Charlieface I asked a question and you answered it. If WinForms is mostly dead now, what is the suggested replacement?

Comment: [MAUI](https://dotnet.microsoft.com/en-us/apps/maui), I _guess_ ?

Comment: Direct replacement is WPF, but you may want to go for MAUI or Blazor depending on requirements.